# How to network multiple docker containers on Windows

Tags: docker

I need to network three containers (web, redis, mysql) all running linux, on a windows desktop host for development.  So far, I've discovered that the bridge network doesn't work in windows, the nat network is no longer supported, and the host network only supports one machine. So I'm stumped.

The use case is for the developer to use a browser on the windows host (desktop) to hit the 'web' docker container on ports 80 and 443, and for the web docker container to access the redis and mysql containers. This is all working fine on my linux desktop host, but my developers don't have Linux machines.

Can somebody point me to the simplest setup to accomplish this?

- three linux containers that connect to each other
- browser on windows host that connects to the web container

No access to the containers from outside the host is needed.

Comment: Have you tried using docker compose? This is a standard use case for it.

Comment: Yes, I use Docker Compose a lot. The same networking that works on Linux doesn't work on WIndows with Docker Desktop providing the engine.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you have to do anything special here, or if the Compose-provided `default` network with its default settings didn't do what you needed.  Do you have a [mcve] demonstrating a setup that works on Linux but not Windows?

Comment: The problems are present when created by  docker compose.  The three machines can talk to each other but the windows host doesn't seem to be able to see the bridge network created by docker composr.